# Manually creating JSON data

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, json, serialization

I have this following code:

```
public ActionResult AjaxHandler(jQueryDataTableParamModel param)
{

    /* PROBLEM */
    var allCompanies = DataRepository.GetCompanies();
    /* PROBLEM */

    var result = from c in allCompanies
        select new[] { c.Name, c.Address, c.Town };

    return Json(new { sEcho = param.sEcho,
                     iTotalRecords = allCompanies.Count(),
                     iTotalDisplayRecords = allCompanies.Count(),
                     aaData = result
        },
                JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

I NEED HELP WRITING

```
DataRepositry.GetCompanies();
```

The part that is marked as PROBLEM can someone help me write a function that returns data that will fit right in to make the code run. I know it suppose to be some kind of Json. But I can't figure out how to make it work.

```
DataRepository.GetCompanies() <- could be any function, I just need to make it work
```

I tried to do this:

```
      var allCompanies = new List<string[]>() {
                new string[] {"1", "Microsoft", "Redmond", "USA"},
                new string[] {"2", "Google", "Mountain View", "USA"},
                new string[] {"3", "Gowi", "Pancevo", "Serbia"}
                };

        var newJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(allCompanies);

        var allCompanies = newJson;
```

That did NOT work.

EXPLANATION:

This is part of a bigger project basically it suppose to populate DataTable, the exact error I am getting. Here is a screen attached.

Comment: What error did you get when you tried?

Comment: Explain "did NOT work" ??? Are you getting an exception, an HTTP error, a client error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating AllCompanies like so:

```
var allCompanies = new[]  { 
  new { Name="XYZ", Country="USA", ID="1"  },
  new { Name="ABC", Country="USA", ID="2"  }, 
  new { Name="DEF", Country="MX",  ID="3"  }
  };
```

My guess is that by not having property names and instead having a bunch of strings, there's no way to generate a proper JSON object with `{key:value}` pairs

Even better, create a Company class like so:

```
public class Company
{
   public string Name;
   public string Country;
   public string ID;
}
```

Comment: This is awesome. Thank you so much! I will accept your answer in 4 min. Just what I needed.